# Unit of measure for DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE

Tags: django

I'm interested in what unit of measure is represented by the 'DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE' variable in django settings. Is it bytes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is bytes. [From Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size):

> The maximum size in **bytes** that a request body may be before a
>   SuspiciousOperation (RequestDataTooBig) is raised.